# How to Install mbstring Extension on Heroku?

Tags: php, heroku

How do I install/enable PHP extension mbstring?

Heroku on its documentation says it's shared by default, and should be enabled once a Composer package require it. I tried adding it in composer.json file but nothing changed.

This is my project's composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "fabpot/goutte": "^3.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2",
        "paquettg/php-html-parser": "^1.7",
        "ext-mbstring": "*"
    }
}
```

After adding last dependency, I ran:

```
heroku run composer update
```

This is the error message I got:

- The requested PHP extension ext-mbstring * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mbstring extension.

Thank you

Comment: Please show your `composer.json` file.

Comment: please check again

Comment: That looks like it should work… is your `composer.lock` file up to date (and tracked by Git)?

Comment: I don't have a gitignore file, so I guess it's tracked. I tried updating composer, but it promoted that mbstring isn't enabled or installed.

Comment: Please make sure it's tracked using something like `git log composer.lock`. It should show at least one commit. What do you mean when you say you tried updating Composer? `composer update`? (That doesn't update Composer, it updates your dependencies.) What was the exact error message you received about `mbstring`? (Please add this to your question, not in a comment.)

Comment: please check the updated question. thank you

Comment: git log composer.lock returned two commits

Comment: You shouldn't be running `composer update` on Heroku. Its ephemeral filesystem won't keep the changes. Instead, run `composer update` _locally_, then commit the changes to `composer.lock`, then push again.

Comment: thank you so much. Please post your answer as an individual reply so I can mark as correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heroku's filesystem [is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). Any changes you make to it after your Dyno spins up can be lost at any time. This happens [at least once per day, and possibly much more frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts).

Additionally, `composer update` is something that I would advise against running on a server. This command installs the *newest available version* of each library (or specific ones if you only `update` specific libraries) that fits what's in `composer.json`. If you ask for `~1.2` in `composer.json` you might get `1.2.1` on your development machine, but `1.2.9` in production. This can lead to some tricky bugs.

The `composer install` command installs the exact versions that are defined in your `composer.lock` file. It is much safer to run on a server, but it does mean that you've got to update your lock file locally and push it to your server.

For both of these reasons you should run `composer update` *locally*. This will update `composer.lock`, which should then be committed and pushed to Heroku. Heroku will run `composer install`, and you should be all set.

(Alternatively, you should also be able to run `composer update 'ext-mbstring'` to leave the rest of your dependencies alone. Be careful with `composer update`, and try to get in the habit of using `composer install` unless you know you need to update some of your dependencies.)